# WinInet and "Negotiate" Authentication

Tags: authentication, wininet, spnego

I've got a web service which I currently connect to and Authenticate against using Basic authentication with WinInet. The way it's currently implemented, is to set INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH, and setting the headers explicitly to the second parameter to `HttpSendRequest`. The benefit to setting the headers explicitly is that we don't get a 401 response first with the list of authentication methods in the "WWW - Authenticate:" header.

We've now enabled `Negotiate` authentication in our service and we want to implement this in the client. In this case, we send a request using `HttpSendRequest` without the `Authorization: Basic` header, and get back a 401 response with the following headers:

```
WWW - Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW - Authenticate: Basic
```

we then simply call `HttpSendRequest` again with the same request handle, and everything appears to work, with the client being authenticated on the server via windows auth.

Is there anyway to explicitly tell `WinInet` to attempt make a request using `Negotiate` protocol?

I'm also not clear as to how `WinInet` handles the second request. I've tried turning on Fiddler, but just having Fiddler enabled seems to break `Negotiate` protocol.